# Map keys into array according to values

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary, angular6

what's the most efficient way to map keys into array according to values based on the condition of the value?

For example, I have a map that contains the File object as the key and boolean as the value like this:

```
map = new Map([
   [file, true],
   [file1, true],
   [file2, false],
   [file3, true],
]);
```

Can I ask what's the shortcut way of creating an array of file objects if map value === true?

**Intended outcome**

`files = [file,file1,file3];`

Appreciate your help thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `entries` to get the keys and the values of the map, then `filter` it by whether a value (the condition) is true, and then `.map` to turn the `[key, value]` into just the key:

```js
const map = new Map([
   ['file', true],
   ['file1', true],
   ['file2', false],
   ['file3', true],
]);
const files = [...map.entries()]
  .filter(([_, cond]) => cond)
  .map(([key]) => key);
console.log(files);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple forEach loop could do the trick here.

```js
const map = new Map([
  ['test', true],
  ['test2', true],
  ['test3', false],
  ['test4', true],
]);

const files = [];

map.forEach((value, key, map) => {
  if (value) {
    files.push(key)
  }

});
console.log(files);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Map.entries` with `filter` and `map` to achieve this. The basic idea is

1. Get an array of all keys/values with `Map.entries`
2. filter that array to only the entries with the value `true`
3. use map to convert from Map entries to array elements.

the code would look something like this.

```
map.entries().filter(entry=>entry[1]).map(entry=>entry[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers above work but if you're after the fastest, perhaps surprisingly using a for loop is faster than the prototype Map and array methods

aka:

```
myMap = new Map([
    ["file", true],
    ["file1", true],
    ["file2", false],
    ["file3", true],
 ]);

const fastest = (files) => {
    const map = [...files]
    const out = []
    for (let i=0; i<map.length; i++){
        if (map[i][1]){
           out.push(map[i][0])
        }
    }
    return out
}

console.log(fastest(myMap))
```

https://coderwall.com/p/kvzbpa/don-t-use-array-foreach-use-for-instead
There are many articles and a lot of literature about this if you have a look around